# Is there a way to Lazy Load on full path only in Angular 2

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

The following paths should demonstrate my route configuration:

- `calendar/2016/11/15` = Day View (`DayModule`)
- `calendar/2016/11` = Month View (`MonthModule`)
- `calendar/2016` = Year View (`YearModule`)

Each view has it's own Module and Components and I'd like to lazy load them individually. Currently the correct components load, but the problem is that when I load, for example, the `MonthModule` then the `YearModule` lazy load it triggered because its base path has already been hit.

i.e. **calendar/2016**/11

I've even arranged my routes as siblings rather than as children:

```
{ // ROUTES
  path: ':year',
  loadChildren: 'app/features/year/year.module#YearModule',
},
{
  path: ':year/:month',
  loadChildren: 'app/features/month/month.module#MonthModule'
},
{
  path: ':year/:month/:day',
  loadChildren: 'app/features/day/day.module#DayModule'
},
```

Now I'd like to avoid a distinct prefix such as `calendar/month/2016/11` because I'd like my user to because to just change the date inn the address bar if they'd like. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: don't do it' put the data into request and transform to dateservices

Comment: You mean like `2016_12_23` and then just rip up the string to reroute?

Comment: remode the date from the address it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{ path: ':year', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: ...},
{ path: ':year/:month', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: ...},
{ path: ':year/:month/:day', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: ...}
```

And the third `pathMatch: 'full'` in 'day' route is not necessary.

Comment: Ah, very simple. Thanks